# How is aZn written in Chinese?

Tags: translation

What is the Chinese word for "aZn"? (Not "Asian-American" but specifically the Chinese name for the subculture of Asian-Americans that refers to itself as "aZn".)

When translating from aZn to Chinese, how does one render the effect of the alternating capitals and lowercases, i.e. translating specifically "aZn PrYdE" and not "Asian[-American cultural] pride"? Does one alternate between using traditional and simplified characters, or using Han and non-Han scripts?

Comment: In English. Here's two example I found: `我哋可以听到AZN PRYDE嘅歌` & `蛤蛤。。2楼还想装呢。。视频偶看过好多次嘞 azn pryde` --- most people are too 崇洋 too feel `aZn`

Comment: Why would you think there is a standard way to do this in Chinese?  It is a neologism in English, specifically shaped by the European alphabet.

Answer (score 2):

Writing in all caps in on line chat or forums is akin to shouting in everyone's ears in real life. It is quite annoying.

Typing capital alphabets in odd positions in a word emphasize a higher volume or higher tone for its reading. For example "a**Z**n" = a**SI**an and it is even more annoying than all caps.

It is considered rude, cheeky and juvenile behavior to type like that: "hEy bRO!"

> how does one render the effect of the alternating capitals and lower cases?

You can imagine using bigger font size or bolder font style for a selected few characters in an otherwise simple phrase, would create this "volume up/ raising tone" effect.

As for using different alphabets to replace the actual one, like "prYde" instead of "Pride". You can do the same in Chinese by using a sound alike character to replace the correct one just for the fun of it.  For example:  "神馬？" instead of "什麼？"; "魂淡" instead of "混蛋" .

Comment: Juvenile is the key word here I think...